# Modify function to display results for all levels of a column and save them in a new dataframe

Tags: r

In the code below I create a function to find the crossover point for all my groups `g1` and `g2`. The problem is that in the line i`nt_adj = 'groupg2', slope_adj = 'vot:groupg2')` I have to set manually the group while I want to have the crossover value for all groups at once and save them in a new dataframe

```
set.seed(1)
vot = rnorm(20, 15, 5)
vot = sort(vot)
phon1 = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
group1 = rep('g1', 20)
df1 = data.frame(vot = vot, phon = phon1, group = group1)

phon2 = c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
group2 = rep('g2', 20)
df2 = data.frame(vot = vot, phon = phon2, group = group2)
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# Fit model
glm2 <- glm(phon ~ vot * group, data = df, family = "binomial")


cross_over <- function(mod, cont_pred, grouping_var = FALSE, 
                       int_adj, slope_adj) {
  
  if (class(mod)[1] == "glm") {
    
    # Store intercept
    int <- summary(mod)$coefficients['(Intercept)', 'Estimate']
    
    # Store continuous x var
    slope <- summary(mod)$coefficients[cont_pred, 'Estimate']
    
    # For bivariate models
    if (grouping_var == FALSE) {
      
      # Calculate crossover
      co <- int / slope * -1
      
      # For models with grouping vars
    } else {
      
      # Calculate group level intercept
      int_derived <- int + summary(mod)$coefficients[int_adj, 'Estimate']
      
      # Calculate slope adjustment
      slope_derived <- slope + summary(mod)$coefficients[slope_adj, 'Estimate']
      
      # Calculate crossover
      co <- int_derived / slope_derived * -1
      
    }
    
    return(co)
    
  } else {
    
    stop("Error: this function requires a glm object\n", 
         "You have provided an object of class: ", class(mod)[1])
  }
  
}


# Get crossover point

# Get crossover point of grouping variables
cross_over(mod = glm2, cont_pred = 'vot', grouping_var = TRUE,
           int_adj = 'groupg2', slope_adj = 'vot:groupg2')
```

Comment: It is not clear where the problem is nor what your expected output should be.

Comment: if you check at the last line of the code you will see that there is a groupg2. this comes from the column name "group" and the "g2" which is one of this column values. The other is "g1" so instead of having to run the function 2 times one with groupg2 and then for groupg1 I want somethin like a loop that will give me the values for both at once

Comment: not sure if sth must change inside the function or its easier to put the function inside a for loop